# null inside jquery selector - check checkboxes and show respective hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check multiple checkboxes in jquery using dynamic variables created with php values. The javascript variables are ok, the problem is that some of these variables can be null and none are checked:

```
    var use             = '#use-$use',
        type            = '#type-$type',
        status          = '#status-$status',
        bhk             = '#bhk-$bhk',
        baths           = '#baths-$baths',
        area_1          = $area_1 > 0 ? '#size1' : null,
        area_2          = $area_2 > 0 ? '#size2' : null,
        sale_price      = $sale_price > 0 ? '#price1' : null,
        monthly_price   = $monthly_price > 0 ? '#price2' : null,
        city            = $city,
        city            = city > 0 ? (parseInt(city) + 1) : 0,
        zone            = $zone,
        zone            = zone > 0 ? (parseInt(zone) + 1) : 0;

    $(use, type, status, bhk, baths, area_1, area_2, sale_price, monthly_price).prop('checked', true);
```

Also, some checkboxes show inputs that are hidden, so if the checkbox is checked the input should be shown:

```
    if ($(area_1).is(':checked')) $(area_1).find('div').show();
```

Is there any clean way to not repeat the above code for the other 3? (area_2, sale_price and monthly_price).

HTML for the checkboxes that have inputs (the 4 have the same classes):

```
    <div class="item">
        <input type="checkbox" id="size1" value="">
        <label for="size1"><span></span>Superficie Construida</label>
        <div class="input hide">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Superficie" name="size[area1]" min="1" max="999" />
            <span class="unit">m²</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a static class to the elements you wish to perform the operation on?  Would be a bit cleaner than selecting upon multiple ids.

Comment: I just know how to create functions, basic stuff. I'm not too experienced in javascript.

Comment: You can give pretty much any element a class using class="something".  So if you gave the element you wanted to target something like class="defaultChecked"  then in the js you could target all of them with $('.defaultChecked')

Comment: It has nothing to do with default. It's a form to edit existing db data, so I need to check based on whats in the database.

Comment: It's just a name/example.  You can name it whatever makes the most sense.

Comment: Yes, but isn't the same thing? Using a class or an id as selector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98609/discussion-between-taplar-and-chazy-chaz).